# ArcGIS Pro saying "Changes in your graphics hardware detected. Close and reopen your map views to continue."

Tags: arcgis-desktop, graphics-card

I am using ArcGIS Pro v2.7 on Windows 10.  ArcGIS Pro keeps displaying a warning window stating *Changes in your graphics hardware detected. Close and reopen your map views to continue.*

[ArcGIS online help offers this advice:](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/mapping/properties/gpu-hardware-change.htm)   *This message may display when your Graphics Processing Unit (GPU) drivers are updated, when your GPU fails or is reset by the driver, or when docking and undocking a laptop computer. When this occurs, ArcGIS Pro suspends rendering of the map views. You can close and reopen the map views to resume rendering.*

[I have used these instruction to update the driver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/update-drivers-in-windows-ec62f46c-ff14-c91d-eead-d7126dc1f7b6) but I see that the driver is the most updated driver available.

I am not docking or undocking the computer.

How do I prevent this annoying pop-up from reoccuring?

Answer (score 3):

Despite the claims of the Windows 10 device manager that the graphics card driver was the most recent driver, forcing a Windows update solved the problem and I no longer see the *Changes in your graphics hardware detected. Close and reopen your map views to continue*.. message in ArcGIS Pro v2.7.

Answer (score 0):

The help says you should update from the manufacturer's website, NOT from windows update:

"If this error message appears frequently without your intervention, you may need to update your GPU drivers from the manufacturer's site."

That would be NVIDIA, AMD, or Intel, or the manufacturer of the laptop/notebook computer.

Comment: Yep, I saw that but thankfully I did not need to take it that far.  IT restrictions on my computer would have triggered IT help to install the drivers.  The simple update solved my problem.  My update would have happened automatically had I been connected to my employer's network but I am working from home and apparently need to trigger that manually.